# Code with me plugin with running application locally

Tags: intellij-idea, pair-programming

Is there a way to do that (run same application with host and test output with postman) or can you advise me if there are alternative ones ?

Answer (score 0):

This is Max from JetBrains Code With Me team. Can you please rephrase the question and provide a little bit more detail? That way we'll be able to help you out quicker.

Comment: Hi Max. When I was doing code pairing with my friend, I was looking for running option but on my local computer too (not just run on host machine and share screen), but couldn 't see that option. I manually cloned via github link and runned that application. So, if there was a run/debug configuration like "download repo and run on my local computer", it would be nice, in my opinion.

Comment: Code With Me is all about collaboration scenarios and unfortunately this use case doesn't fit into our vision. We can't make any promises that this will ever be implemented